# Custom recover password script

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I've written so far in Excel because it was easy to use SendKeys to the app one cell at a time once the list is fully generated. That part is done. The app takes infinite password attempts... thankfully!

I now have 3 columns: prefix, core, suffix.

I'm 95% sure it's some combination of these elements, since that's what I use for all my passwords.

I must have entered my password wrong twice when creating it. So assuming my password is `hiPassword2`, it could have been typed as:

```
hiPassword1
hiPassword3
HiPassword2
HIPassword2
JiPassword2
hiOassword1
etc.
```

So it seems a combination of a recursive algorithm + caps on certain letters + nearby keys. I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed with where to start.

Comment: Sounds like a very badly made app if it allows infinite attempts...

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: No Callum, it's by design, and it's appropriate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a simple backtracking question [e.g. to print all permutations of a string]that you've to try. However, for your use case - at few indexes or for character type you'll have rule.

As an illustration, the last character has to be a number - so values available for this index is 0-9, while values available for other characters are [a-z A-Z].

You can also have rule that your 3rd character can only be 'P' and either in small or caps - which again limits number of values available for a position.

So, all in all it is a normal `permutation backtracking` with some rules in place. You may want to google the above term as is or have a look at this question, [Permutation of string using backtracking algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470605/permutation-of-string-using-backtracking-algorithm)

Comment: Thank you.  The technical term "permutation backtracking" is what I need to get started.